# Is this question about differentiability wrong?

Tags: derivatives, continuity, vector-analysis

In my textbook, I found the following exercise:

> Show that the following vector field is differentiable at $(0,0,0)$:
>   $$G(x,y)=\left(\frac {x^3 + y^3}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}},\frac {1}{x^2 + y^2 + 1}\right)$$

However, I see that it is not even continuous at the origin, so it cannot be, in any way, differentiable. Is this right or am I missing something?

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The author should have specified that we define $G(0,0)$ to be $(0,0)$ (as this is the value which makes $G$ continuous).

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I though, but I was not sure if it is a trick question as, the way it is written, nothing can be done to prove differentiability.

Comment: Also, (0,0,0) has 3 entries even though G only takes 2 inputs. ​ ​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $G=(G_1,G_2)$. $G$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ if and only if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are differentiable there.

$G_2$ is obviously differentiable. For $G_1$, the partial derivatives are each $0$:

$$\frac{\partial G_1}{\partial x} (0,0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{G_1(h+0,0) - G_1(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{h^3}{|h|}}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} |h| = 0$$

One gets $\frac{\partial G_1}{\partial y}(0,0)$ by symmetry. Now recall that $G_1$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ if and only if the following limit exists and equals $0$:

$$\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)} \frac{G_1(0+h,0+k) - G_1(0,0) - \frac{\partial G_1}{\partial x}(0,0) h - \frac{\partial G_1}{\partial y}(0,0)k}{\sqrt{h^2+ k^2}}$$

Convert to polar coordinates to see why this is in fact the case.

Comment: Thank you! I missed an *h* somewhere in the partial derivative limit.

Comment: yes, essentially $G_1$ is $O(r^2)$ at the origin, which shows that it is first differentiable at the origin with $0$ gradient.